# Creating a page for Drupal Module

Tags: routes, 7

I'm very much new to Drupal. I need to bring a functionality such that user gives some input, say feedback in some pages which will be stored into a custom table (made by me) in drupal database. So I created a custom module that'll will save the inputs into database (through form POST).

Now the problem is, I need to show all these inputs to authorized user. There should be menu link in Drupal menu after logging in and clicking on it should take to a page where I should list all these inputs.

If I bring another module, and set a url, while navigating to that url, what I see is a blank page and there I can show anything. It's fine but I need to show Drupal menu and Drupal like interface. How can I achieve it?

Comment: Why are you creating a custom module to get user input?  Why can't you use one of the standard content types that comes with Drupal (with or without fields extensions)?

Comment: Try to work with Drupal instead of working around Drupal. Consider existing modules like [Webform](http://drupal.org/project/webform). If you choose custom code, make sure you understand the hook system. [hook_menu()](http://api.drupal.org/hook_menu) allows you route a URL to a PHP function. Learn the [Form API](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21topics%21forms_api_reference.html/7) to build your form. Use [hook_schema()](http://api.drupal.org/hook_menu) to define your custom table. Consider [drupal_write_record()](http://api.drupal.org/drupal_write_record) to write to the database.